# hide ViewFlipper views

Tags: android, view, scrollview

I have a ViewFlipper with several ScrollViews in it.
On the first ScrollView I have a radiobutton group.

At start up when no radiobutton is checked, I would like to hide all ScrollViews and disallow swiping.
When radiobutton 1 is checked I would like only certain ScrollViews to be visible and swiping left or right should only show those ones.
For radiobutton 2 it's other ScrollViews etc..

Is this possible?

I tried with setting the visibility of the scrollviews to View.GONE, but that doesn't prevent swiping to them.

I would be great if this was possible.

--edit--

I managed to find

```
viewFlipper.removeViewAt(1);
```

But now I'm stuck on the question to restore the view without restarting the activity.
Is there a way to force the activity to reload it's layout?
Or should I not use RemoveViewAt(..) and it there another way to just disable the view.

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 2):

solved it...

In stead of using

```
viewFlipper.next();
```

I check first whick radiobutton is checked and then use

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild( viewnumber );
```

to make it go the view that is allowed for that radiobutton.